# form validation for text input with default values

Tags: php, validation, forms

I have a form with 10 input textboxes and each of them have a default value like 'First Name', 'Last Name'. I used onblur and onfocus on these elements since there was no description beside the textbox to indicate what each box is for. Sample code:

```
    <input type="text" id="o_fname" name="o_fname" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['o_fname']) ) echo $_POST['o_fname']; else echo 'First Name'; ?>" tabindex="1" size="36" style="background:#000000;color:#8e8e8e;border-color:#D8D8D8;height:22px;width:200px;" onFocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''; " onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;">
```

I want to validate this form on the same page, i tried my jquery stuff but the problem was that the textbox had a default value and jquery was assuming that something was entered into the box and i was not validating properly... any suggestions as to how can i validate this page dynamically so that user cannot submit the form unless he enters all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution, here it is to help others:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

Then write a script to do a custom validation on the form fields and it will check if the entered value is First Name or not.

Answer (score 0):

Only use a default value if that value is valid. Otherwise, use `<label>` to indicate what a field is for. This is also important for accessibility.

Legit places to use default values:

- today's date in a date field in the
  correct format
- default select box value of the most
  commonly selected option
- checkbox/radio set to the most common
  choice

Comment: We cannot change what a client wants the page to look like right? the client did not want labels, only textboxes with default values which need to be validated before the form was submitted. i wrote the script for validation of the form once it is submitted.

Comment: Tell the client that if they don't have labels, at least in the code, they are opening themselves up to 508 lawsuits from the visually impaired. You can use that as leverage to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

either create a json object with all the fields and their related default values or create `vars` in javascript

Then when the form is submitted compare the submitted values to the default values and if none of the values match the associated default values continue with the submission

Comment: I already created a validation where the values are checked for default values once the form was submitted. But i wanted something that will check the form on the spot, before submitting.